# Getting last value in tikz foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

I tried this, but it doesn't work as intended:

```
\foreach \x/\index in {4/0,5/1,19/2} {
  \ifnum \index > 0
     % use lastx
  \fi
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\x} 
}
```

How do I set `\lastx` properly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the additional facilities of `foreach` macro given in the manual by adding `pgfmath` package too. For some reason, `(initially 4)` option is not working if TikZ is not fully loaded so you can define it externally.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\begin{document}
\def\lastx{4}
\foreach \x[count=\xi from 2,remember=\x as \lastx] in {5,19,20,25} {
This variable \x, the value before was \lastx\space  and it is the argument \xi\space in the list.\par
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Assignments in a `\foreach` are local, so you can use `\xdef\lastx{\x}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\lastx}{}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x/\index in {4/0,5/1,19/2} {
  \ifnum \index > 0
     % use lastx
  \fi
  \xdef\lastx{\x} 
}

Last x was \lastx
\end{document}
```