# \foreach has a problem with ‘initially’ argument in remember part

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Is there an error in my code or did I find a bug? It seems like the `\foreach` statement doesn’t increase `\lastn` if there is an `initally (value)` but it works with a manually given initially value (`\def\lastn`).

This is what I expect …

[image: right]

… and that is what I get …

[image: wrong]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (2,0) {B};
    \node (C) at (4,0) {C};
    \node (D) at (6,0) {D};
%   DOESN'T WORK
%   \foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn (initially A)] in {B,C,D} {
%       \draw [->] (\lastn) -- (\n);
%   }
%   WORKS
    \def\lastn{A}
    \foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn] in {B,C,D} {
        \draw [->] (\lastn) -- (\n);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me with CVS version but not with CTAN version.

Comment: Replacing `{B,C,D}` with `{B,...,D}` also works correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Tikz foreach with two variables and the remember option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30938) • Related: [`PGF`/TikZ bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3116557&group_id=142562&atid=752792)

Comment: The same issue here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66844/getting-last-value-in-tikz-foreach In the stable release the pattern somehow should be inline with the initial value otherwise it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: I think the problem is present again with the latest CVS version of pgf. Can anyone confirm

Comment: I confirm that the issue is still there with in the TeXLive 2013 version of TikZ (v 2.10, rcs rev 1.76)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with `\newforeach`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{loops}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (2,0) {B};
\node (C) at (4,0) {C};
\node (D) at (6,0) {D};
\newforeach \n [remember=\n as \lastn initially A] in {B,C,D}
  \draw [->] (\lastn) -- (\n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can try also

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{loops}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,1) [circle,draw,red] {
  \foxloop [remember=#1 as \x initially A] {B,C,D,E,F,G,H}{%
    $\overrightarrow{\x#1}$\iflastfox.\else,\space\fi
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, thats a workaround, but shouldn’t this bug be fixed in TikI?

Comment: Where does `\newforeach` come from?

Comment: _loops_ package.