# Variables in TikZ and other basic programming concepts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm discovering TikZ. I'm using it to draw a fairly complex automaton (something around 20 states). I did it the all manual way (ie by specifying all the states and all the connections). Though it was *very* long and *really* boring, so now I try to do it the correct way (ie by doing some looping).

Though I encounter a kinda big problem: I'd like to program a bit but I don't know what are the common tools (ie variables and things like that) available to me. I do know the basis of TeX and even started reading the TeX book, but I'm not advanced in it yet and still lack the basis.

Here for example I'd like to loop through a list of node and link it to the next one. For that I'd like to memorize the last node I went through so that it can be the departure of my next link (I tried to provide a MWE but my actual automaton is way bigger).

My attempt:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[initial,state]    (A)                    {A};
  \node[state]            (B) [right of=A]       {B};
  \node[state]            (C) [right of=B]       {C};
  \node[state, accepting] (D) [right of=C]       {D};


  \newcommand\from{A}
  \foreach \to in {B, C, D}
  {
    \path (\from) edge [-] (\to);
    \renewcommand\from{\to};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried `\def` instead of `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`, but to no avail.

So what I'd like is a pointer towards a good tutorial where I could grab all those basic principles, because the TikZ/pgf manual is large and I didn't find the info I need. The principles I'd like to learn are the basis of TikZ programming.

PS: I guess my question must have been asked before. However I didn't find an answer in the questions I got as a result for my research.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks innocent but actually your question is linked to TeX groups, expansion and global/local definitions. Hence it is indeed quite broad to tackle it here and goes well beyond TikZ to TeX programming.

A few quick comments:

- `\foreach` operates in a TeX group. Among other peculiarities, the definitions are only valid inside this group but vanish outside this group. So in a way, every loop of `\foreach` resets the variables to their original setting. In your example `\from` becomes `A` again.
- You can use the `[remember=<foreach variable> as <another macro name]` key to keep the previous value in the memory. Hence the definition becomes immune to group enter/exit problems.
- TikZ `\foreach` understands `a,...,z,A,...,Z` as a repeating array. So in your example there is an easy way out.
- `minimal` class is not meant for mortals like us. It's more of a testing environment for TeXnicians (well I'm really approximating here) instead you can use `article` or `standalone`.

First, the expansion,grouping etc. solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[initial,state]    (A)                    {A};
  \node[state]            (B) [below right of=A]       {B};
  \node[state]            (C) [right of=B]       {C};
  \node[state, accepting] (D) [above right of=C]       {D};


  \newcommand\from{A}
  \foreach \too in {B, C, D}
  {
    \path (\from) edge [-] (\too);
    \xdef\from{\too}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The bottom line is due to my poor image cropping. And here is a `remember` solution.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[initial,state]    (A)                    {A};
  \node[state]            (B) [below right of=A]       {B};
  \node[state]            (C) [right of=B]       {C};
  \node[state, accepting] (D) [above right of=C]       {D};

\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B,...,D}{
% "initially" works only with ... I've recently found it but 
% didn't have time to report it.
    \path (\lastx) edge [-] (\x);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You might be better off with variable names that are not existing (La)TeX macros. So I've changed to `\x`.

Comment: Since you're using xdef you don't need the expandafters, and you could use `\global\let\from=\to`

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes, I don't know what I was thinking. Fixing in a sec. It's all the weird QTikZ habits.

Comment: *"initially" works only with ... I've recently found it*. See [here for more](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79586/foreach-has-a-problem-with-initially-argument-in-remember-part/79644#79644).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the comments on that question too but didn't see that it's already reported so I don't need to do anything :)