# Change related to \foreach \x[remember=\x as \MyLastx] in TeXLive2019

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, texlive-2019

I just recently upgraded to TeXLive2019 and the code below fails to compile in TeXLive2019 with the message

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. 
> <argument> \MyLastx
> ```

But compiles fine in TeXLive2018.

However, if I uncomment the

```
%\newcommand{\MyLastx}{1}
```

line then it also works in TeXLive2019.

Is this an issue with TeXLive2019 or an issue with my code that should not have worked in TeXLive2019?

### References

- [Getting last value in tikz foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66849/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\MyWidth}

%\newcommand{\MyLastx}{1}% <--- NOT needed in TeXLive2018, but is needed in TexLive2019

\newcommand*{\ForeachOverRange}[1]{%
    \foreach \x[remember=\x as \MyLastx] in {#1} {%
        %% Do something here
        \typeout{\x}%
    }%
    \settowidth{\MyWidth}{\fbox{\MyLastx}}%
}%

\begin{document}
Some before text

\ForeachOverRange{1,...,3}

Some after text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason I need to include an extra space in the error message as the `<argument>` would not display unless I added a leading space following the `<`.

Comment: Might it have to do with scoping? The code essentially uses `\MyLastx` after the loop context for which it has been defined. What value would you expect `\MyLastx` to have in the `\settowidth` line? The last value of the loop variable?

Comment: The documentation for `/pgf/foreach/remember` says *This key allows the item value stored in `<variable>` to be remembered during the next iteration,stored in `<macro>`.* This seems to suggest that the assignment is indeed intended to be local to the loop code only.

Comment: Did someone actually test the code with TL 2019? With the TL from Debian unstable, which should be 2019, it works *as is* (i.e., without uncommenting the `\newcommand{\MyLastx}{1}` that is supposedly needed to make the example work in TL 2019).  Besides, `\MyWidth` **is** set to the width of `\fbox{\MyLastx}` where `\MyLastx` is the last value of the iteration. So?..

Comment: @frougon I didn't check with TeX live, but I checked with an up-to-date MikTeX, which should be the same package wise and could reproduce the behaviour the question describes. That is I get an `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \MyLastx` if `\newcommand{\MyLastx}{1}` is commented out. According to `\lisftiles `I have `tikz.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)`, which should be the most recent release of Ti*k*Z. I never know with the TeX live from Linux distros: At least on Ubuntu the version is frozen quite early on and often outdated on release.

Comment: @moewe You're right, this is exactly why I added the precision that I'm testing on Debian unstable. My Ti*k*Z version is older than yours (`Package: tikz 2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)`), so the question seems fine. It should be possible to use `\gdef` or some other command prefixed with `\global` inside the loop to propagate the desired value outside, but I guess the OP knows that. Sorry for the noise (at least, we now have a relatively tight framing of the first version showing a different behavior for the problem at hand).

Comment: @frougon: Yeah I am familiar with using a `\global`: That is an alternate solution listed at the question listed in the _References_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to stick my neck out and say that the behaviour observed with TeX live 2019 (Ti*k*Z 3.1.4b) is intentional, but at the very least consistent with the documentation. If `remember` previously made the variable available outside of the loop that was not documented behaviour and could not be relied upon.

The documentation of `remember` says (and has said this for quite a while – I checked with 3.0.1a)

> `/pgf/foreach/remember=<variable> as <macro> (initially <value>)` (no default)
>
> This key allows the item value stored in `<variable>` to be remembered during the next iteration, stored in `<macro>`.
>   If a variable is evaluated, the result of this evaluation is remembered.
>   By default the value of `<variable>` is zero for the first iteration, however, the optional (initially `<value>`) statement, allows the `<macro>` to be initially defined as `<value>`.

The key here is the *to be remembered during the next iteration*, which only guarantees that the variable is available in the next iteration step, but not after the loop.

In previous versions of PGF this was not the case, which led to unexpected behaviour and accidental macro overwrites as in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/702.  Therefore the decision was made to strictly restrict the scope of the `remember` variable to the loop body.

If you want to carry the value of the loop variable out of the loop, you can use an `\xdef` assignment as suggested in [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66847/35864) to [Getting last value in tikz foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66844/35864). If you think a function for this would be a generally useful feature, you can open a feature request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues.

Comment: Your hunch is correct. I edited the “official” statement into it.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for the official clarification.